# python package import from the root

Tags: python

I have a following directory structure:

```
main_work/
 data_processing/
  data_extraction.py
  data_selector.py
```

data_selector.py:

```
from data_extraction import connect_to_db
```

If I start working in main_work and want to do

```
from data_processing import data_selector as ds
```

it throws me an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_extraction'
```

So, the import in data_selector.py takes into account only current folder (main_work) and doesnt go one level deeper into data_processing.

I need to be able to do from main_work following:
from data_processing import data_selector as ds

and from data_processing following:
import data_selector

How do I achieve those two functionalities?

Comment: do you have a  `__inti__.py` file in `data_processing `. You need it

Comment: I added it, didnt work

Comment: see my answer below. btw `__inti__` was a typo

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add your folder to the [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), this way python will know where to look for the modules you want to import.

Comment: Several people will be working on it, I think I need a universal solution

Answer (score 0):

You need the following structure

```
main_work/
  data_processing/
    __init__.py
    data_extraction.py
    data_selector.py
```

and in `data_selector.py`

```
from .data_extraction import connect_to_db
```

the `.` specifies that it should look in the same directory as the `data_selector` module

Comment: Then it says: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package